# How to access a Field in a Dynpro i Added via the Dict in the PAI?

Tags: abap

I have the following question:

I have a dypro and added via the layout builder a dict delement: `mara-matnr`

Now I see it in my element list:
[image]

Now I wanted to know, how to access the value of the `matnr` in my PAI which looks like this:

```
MODULE user_command_1000 INPUT.
  " HOW TO ACCESS THE VALUE OF MATNR HERE?
ENDMODULE.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to guess what you did to get that far, and I’d strongly recommend not to continue along that road. What I’d rather do is

- create a new dictionary **structure** (not a transparent table!) that contains the screen fields you need
- use the `TABLES` statement with the structure to declare a global variable in your program or function pool top include
- place the fields of the structure on the screen, just like you did with the `MARA` fields in your example
- use the fields of your global variable in your coding

The way you prepared the screen, you would have to add a global variable named `MARA` with the structure of the transparent table `MARA`, probably using the statement `TABLES mara.` While this is perfectly possible, it’s also **really dangerous** - you could end up changing the database contents inadvertedly, especially since you seem to be rather new to the system.

Comment: can I find a example for this somewhere?

Comment: In every ABAP Development book or course that is worth its money.